# React Context - Context and Child render are not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm playing with [REACT context](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) trying to update a login from a Child component to an App component when I press the button on the Child component.

Full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mccarthy-lrgk8?file=/src/App.js).

So there are two components : App and Child in the same file.

Here is my UserContext with the login variable and the function to update the login (with loginUpdated)

```
const UserContext = React.createContext({
    login: 'defaultLogin',
    updateLogin: (loginUpdated) => {}
});
```

In the App component, I've got my UserContext.Provider surrounding the Child component :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.appLoginUpdate = this.appLoginUpdate.bind(this); 

        this.state = {
            login: "AppLoginValue"
        }
    }

    appLoginUpdate(login) {
        console.log("1. appLoginUpdate method => login value: ", login)

        this.setState({
            login: login
        })

        console.log("2. appLoginUpdateLogin method after state update :", this.state.login)
    }

    render() {
        const contextValue = {
            login: "contextValueLogin",
            updateLogin: this.appLoginUpdate
        }
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                <Child />
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

And finally I've got the Child component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    static contextType = UserContext;

    handleClick() {
        this.context.updateLogin("ChildValueLogin")
    }

    render() {
        console.log("3. Context login value : ", this.context.login)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.context.login}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>UPDATE LOGIN</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Before clicking on "UPDATE LOGIN" button, I've got this in the console :

```
3. Context login value :  contextValueLogin
```

[ That's OK, this is the value given to contextValue.login in the App ]

When a first click on the "UPDATE LOGIN" button, I've got this in the console :

```
1. appLoginUpdate method => login value:  ChildValueLogin
```

[ That's OK, expected value for login argument ]

```
2. appLoginUpdateLogin method after state update : AppLoginValue
```

[ That's bad, this.state has not been updated ]

```
3. Context login value :  contextValueLogin
```

[ That's bad too ]

When I click again :

```
1. appLoginUpdate method => login value:  ChildValueLogin
```

[ OK again ]

```
2. appLoginUpdateLogin method after state update : ChildValueLogin
```

[ Now it's OK after second click ?! ]

```
3. Context login value :  contextValueLogin
```

[ Bad again, never updated ]

I would like you to help me finding out what are my problems in this code please. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` updates state asynchronously. Change setState function to

```
this.setState({
      login: login
}, () => {
      console.log(
        "2. appLoginUpdateLogin method after state update :", this.state.login
     );
});
```

to see the changed state.

`setState` function takes an optional callback function parameter which is called **after state has been updated**. If you want to see the changes in the state immediately after updating it, you need to put your `console.log` statement inside this callback function

You also need to change

```
const contextValue = {
    login: "contextValueLogin",           <----- hard-coded string
    updateLogin: this.appLoginUpdate
};
```

to

```
const contextValue = {
  login: this.state.login,
  updateLogin: this.appLoginUpdate
};
```

to log the updated value of `this.context.login`

After making the above mentioned changes, output on the console will be:

before update button click

```
3. Context login value :  AppLoginValue
```

after update button click

```
1. appLoginUpdate method => login value:  ChildValueLogin 
3. Context login value :  ChildValueLogin 
2. appLoginUpdateLogin method after state update : ChildValueLogin
```